# AngularJS - List - conditionally format an item in a list based on value

Tags: angularjs

I'm using  JSON binding to the following -

a fact contains  a name    so  - fact.name = 'ABC',  fact.name ='XYZ'

ion-list

```
 ion-item ng-repeat="fact in facts" item="fact" 


 if fact contains  ABC I want to show the item like this.

   use ABC class and show it in BOLD

if fact contains   XYZ  I want to show the itme like this.

use XYZ class and show in RED


    and so on
```

How do I conditionally show / format a list item based on the value?

Comment: You can apply ng-class based on your conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply your css using ng-class:

```
<li ng-class="{'ABC': fact.name == 'ABC', 'XYZ': fact.name == 'XYZ'}></li>
```

If you wanna apply css if the fact.name contains a string:

```
 <li ng-class="{'ABC': fact.name.indexOf('ABC') > -1, 'XYZ': fact.name.indexOf('XYZ') > -1}></li>
```

If you are sure that your css class name and the fact.name matches always, you can in fact directly bind it to the class attribute.

```
 <li class="{{fact.name}}" style="{{ fact.name == 'ABC' ? 'font-weight:bold':'color:red'}}"></li>
```

Note: It is not a good practice to have styles go separately when you have css class defined. I would prefer having these styles moved to the css classes appropriately.

Comment: This will work when the name equals to a string, not if it just contains it.

Comment: @Shomz Thanks for correcting. I updated the code for contains case